# How do I install/update to Postgres 9.4?

Tags: database, postgresql, server

I just installeed Postgres, but it seems to have installed 9.3 and I'd like to start with 9.4

I simply did **apt-get install postgresql** from a new **Ubuntu 14.04.1** machine.

http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

says you can do:

```
apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

but when I try that I get:

```
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'postgresql-9.4
```

Okay, so I try the section below where you add the PostgreSQL Apt Repository but that can't find anything either.

Is 9.4 not in the package managers yet? Am I doing something horribly wrong?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

postgresql-9.4 is not available in [14.04 "Trusty"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/database/).  It was added in [14.10 "Utopic"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/database/).  It may be back ported in the future.

The directions on the [PostgreSQL Ubuntu Download page](http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) are missing a command.  [Their wiki guide](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt#Quickstart) has the correct procedure.  You must run `apt-get update` before trying to install.  This will cause the system to read changes to the sources.

Comment: Thanks @Schwern, I had the wrong codename too so that was very helpful.

Comment: The script at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Apt#Quickstart did it for me. https://alioth.debian.org/scm/loggerhead/pkg-postgresql/postgresql-common/trunk/download/head:/apt.postgresql.org.s-20130224224205-px3qyst90b3xp8zj-1/apt.postgresql.org.sh

Answer (score 57):

You can add it from the instructions in the page

http://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/

- Create the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list, and add a line for the repository

  ```
  deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main
  ```
- Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists

  ```
  wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
  ```

Answer (score 12):

If you're trying to install on Ubuntu 14.04 "Trusty", you can follow these steps:

To check your version:

```
$ lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

1) Create new apt repo file for postgres

```
$ echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list
```

2) Import repository signing key and update packages list

```
$ sudo wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
$ sudo apt-get update
```

3) Install Postgres

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

credit: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/02/install-postgresql-ubuntu-14-04/

Answer (score 7):

Below are steps to install PostgreSQL 9.4 on Ubuntu 14.04.

**[Reference taken from this Article:](http://www.dbrnd.com/2016/04/postgresql-how-to-install-postgresql-9-4-on-ubuntu-14-04/)**

**First, check the version of Ubuntu:**

```
lsb_release -sc
```

**You need to add the latest PostgreSQL repository for the latest version, otherwise It will install PostgreSQL 9.3. This is for trusty version.**

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb https://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ trusty-pgdg main"
```

**Update and Install PostgreSQL 9.4:**

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.4
```

**Default postgres super user and postgres database is created. You need to set a password for the postgres super user.**

```
ubuntu@:~$ sudo passwd postgres
Enter new UNIX password:****
Retype new UNIX password:****
passwd: password updated successfully
```

**If service is not started, you can start the PostgreSQL service.**

```
sudo service postgresql start
```

**Connect PostgreSQL server using postgres user:**

```
ubuntu@:~$ su postgres
Password:****
```

**Create a sample database:**

```
createdb database_name
```

**Connect to that database:**

```
psql -d database_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps to install postgresql. Open the terminal (Ctrl + Alt + t) and then write down the following command line

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget -q https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc -O - | sudo apt-key add -


sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

If postgresql installed successfully then it will return this after writing this command

```
psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.3
```

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is an open source object-relational database system. It is one of leading database server used for production servers. PostgreSQL allows us to execute stored procedures in various programming languages, like PHP, C/C++, Python, Java, Perl, Ruby and its own PL/pgSQL, which is similar to Oracle’s PL/SQL.

Postgres database is used the persistent store of data

**Install** Postgres

```
yum install postgres
```

(Note : remember the password for the postgres user – you need it later)

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.6
```

Setting up Postgres

Launch pgAdmin.

Connect to the local server.  Use localhost for the server name, postgres for the username and the password you used when you installed Postgres.
You need to be root to perform this command.Note: If you did not set password during installation (sudo apt-get install postgresql), then you can set it as follows:

￼

```
sudo -u postgres psql postgres
```

On the postgres client prompt, use the following command to set the password.

```
alter user postgres with password 'postgres';
```

Connect to PostgreSQL

After installing PostgreSQL database server, by default,, it creates a user ‘postgres’ with role ‘postgres’. It also creates a system account with same name ‘postgres’. So to connect to postgres server, log in to your system as user postgres and connect database.

```
$ sudo su - postgres
$ psql
```

Now you are logged in to PostgreSQL database server. To check login info use following command from database command prompt.

```
postgres-# \conninfo
```

To disconnect from PostgreSQL database command prompt just type below command and press enter. It will return you back to Ubuntu command prompt.

```
postgres-# \q
```